# Sheet behaving very slow with hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

For some reason this shee is behaving very sluggish anytime the macro runs. This is becoming problematic as every time I try to change information on unhidden cells that are not part of the range, it still runs an update and takes nearly 5-10 seconds to complete.

What changes to the formula need to take place to midigate this problem?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range


    For Each c In Range("A7:A98")
        If c.Value = 0 And c.Value = vbNullString Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c

    For Each c In Range("A7:A98")
        If c.Value <> 0 And c.Value <> vbNullString Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Worst, your code doesn't even run! Target <> Range leads to type mismatch! But I accept optimization as a valid question!

Comment: `If Target <> Range("A7:A98") Then`  <~~ this is wrong.

Comment: I forgot I had that there. If Target <> Range("A7:A98") Then was me butchering the code trying to figure out how to ignore the cells other than the ones being checked... Clearly it didn't work. i will edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic appears sketchy and it is a little hard to tell what you are trying to do but your logical can be shortened and used to determine the boolean .Hidden.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:A98")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim trgt As Range
        For Each trgt In Intersect(Target, Range("A7:A98"))
            trgt.EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(trgt.Value = vbNullString)
        Next trgt
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rCheck As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rHide As Range
    Dim lCalc As XlCalculation

    Set rCheck = Me.Range("A7:A98")

    With Application
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    If Not Intersect(Target, rCheck) Is Nothing Then
        rCheck.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        For Each rCell In rCheck
            If rCell.Value = 0 And rCell.Value = vbNullString Then
                If rHide Is Nothing Then
                    Set rHide = rCell
                Else
                    Set rHide = Union(rHide, rCell)
                End If
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If

    If Not rHide Is Nothing Then rHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True

CleanExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = lCalc
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```